# Getting duplicate records to show in same row

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select

Hello I have a table that Has a movie name, the date it was released, the cost and the revenue. I am trying to write a query to display how many movies were released per month

```
CREATE TABLE movies_200249154(

movieName VARCHAR(30),
releaseDate DATE,
costInMillions INT (20),
revenueInMillions INT (20)

);
```

Above is my table

Here is my current query

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW (monthname(releaseDate)) AS 'Month released', COUNT(*)movieName
FROM movies_200249154
GROUP BY movieName;
```

Right now my query will display the month, and the count for the movie (always being 1) and shows duplicates. If I use SELECT DISTINCT it only displays 1 movie per month. Seemingly forgetting about the other data.

What I need is for my query to display the month AND the amount of movies released that month. For example it currently repeats June 4 times with a count of 1. The query I need would display June and a count of 4.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: MySQL <> SQL-Server which is it?  And per a solution... you're grouping by moviename, thus every movie's information will be on a separate row.  You need to group by month since your counting the movies PER month.  Additionally you don't need a distinct when performing a group by in this case.  IMO distinct should only be used when you have duplicate data in a result set that you need to truly eliminate; otherwise when using aggregation a group by is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MONTH` function of MySQL and `group by` with `count` to get the required value, e.g.:

```
SELECT MONTH(releaseDate), count(*)
FROM movies
GROUP BY MONTH(releaseDate);
```

Comment: @AM you can accept the answer as correct if it has helped you.